# Sony Access Log (Playstation Network) does not exists

Tags: access-control, account-security, audit

Yesterday my wife receive some emails from Sony confirming her purchases on Playstation Network. The only problem is: she was with my side watching Netflix on the smart Tv.
The purchased items is a pre-order of the new Call of Duty and an annual subscription to PS plus. **We do not recognise this purchases, obviously.**

After changing the password and set up the 2-factor authentication, we tried to contact Playstation support to revert this purchases and get more information about this.

1. Playstation Network web page does not have any Access Log feature;
2. In contact with the online support, they claim that the purchase was made by the device itself;
3. They also claims that they do not have any access log control;
4. They state that there nothing they can do.

**Is it possible that Sony do not have any access log control?**

**Is there any law/regulation applied for cases like this?**

**NIST publications could be used as reference for juridical processes, regarding this?**

As an IT guys, I never saw any system without Access Log control. For me, their statement is bullshit.

Hope someone could help me clarify this. Thanks in advance for your time.

Reference: https://www.nist.gov

Comment: Did your wife retyped a code on her phone that one of her friends sent her?

Comment: One doesn't have to access the original account to perform an unauthorized transaction.

Comment: @tungsten no, she didn't. We apply 2-factor auth AFTER the purchase. By the way, we achieve a refund of all the value after a deep talk with the support. Clearly they notice something on the logs, to change their resolution approach radically.